# Filling Cells, New Entry Always At The Top With Sequential Number Added To It

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm quite new to VBA in Excel, but I need it for a small project I'm working on and could use your help.

What I need to do is populate a list on a separate sheet ("machines") in a workbook from another sheet ("NewMachine") that I enter information on, this entered information on the "NewMachine" sheet is cleared, ready for another entry.

I would like to have the new entries come in at the top of the list and have 2 sequential numbers added to that row, corresponding to the new entry.

Essentially

Column A Column B Column C

...      ...      ...

2        2        Information

1        1        Information

This is the code i have so far:

```
Sub capturedata()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set wks = Sheets("Machines")

lastrow = wks.Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = Cells(6, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = Cells(7, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 5).Value = Cells(8, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 6).Value = Cells(9, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 7).Value = Cells(10, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 8).Value = Cells(11, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 9).Value = Cells(12, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 10).Value = Cells(13, 2).Value
wks.Cells(lastrow + 1, 11).Value = Cells(14, 2).Value


Range("B6:B14").ClearContents

End Sub
```

This allows me to enter the information to populate the list from top down, but not much else.

Answer (score 0):

> new entries come in at the top of the list

Insert a new row above 2nd row instead of looking for `lastrow`

Also you can copy the whole range once instead of going through each cells.

```
Sub capturedata()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Sheets("Machines")

    With wks
        .Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert
        .Range("C2:K2") = Range("B6:B14").Value
    End With

    Range("B6:B14").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Máté, thanks for your reply. When using your code though, i enter my data on one sheet to be transferred to the other, but when i click the button to perform the macro, it writes the first cell i entered across the entire row that it's meant to have all the information displayed?

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me. Please try to debug it.